# Subfile Sectioning number

Tags: sectioning, formatting, packages, subfiles

So I want to write my Script in LaTex and wanted to Structure it using the Subfile Package. I managed to include it and the main.tex file is working as wanted.

My problem now is, that when i want to work on the Subfiles indenpendetly, the Chpator Numbering is wrong.

Here is an Example:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subfile{subfile.tex}

\end{document}
```

and the subfile.tex:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

When i now Compile the main.tex, the Numbering is right with

1. Test

1.1 subsection

when i now open the subfile the numbering is wrong it shows only

0.1 subsection.

any way to fix it?

Comment: I'd just ignore it. In the end you are probably going to compile the full file and the numbering will be as expected. Or you move the `\section` into `subfile.tex`.

Comment: i'd like to not ignore it, because sometimes i want to share only a specific section with someone and not the whole document. Also i don't only have one subsection, i got several subsections, so if i move the Section in the subfile.tex it would always start counting the subsections at 1

Comment: You should write `\ifnum\value{section}=0\section{Test}\fi` into subfile.tex, before `\subsection{Subsection}`.

Comment: This works only for one subsection, but if i have 2 subsections, the secon subsection starts at at 1 again, when compiling it atllone.

Comment: @Yannis, So the pragmatic solution is to a) compile your main-document, b) extract the relevant pages from the pdf, e.g. via the print-menu of your application. // In terms of workflow you may also want to inspect https://www.ctan.org/topic/cond-comp .